# Figure inscribed inside a circle.

Tags: triangles

In the given figure, find the $MO\times MS$ of the circle:
[image: figure]
Given that $MP = 16$ and $MQ = 10$

I know I have to prove $\triangle PSM$ and $\triangle NQM$ similar to get ratio.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to prove $\triangle PSM$ and $\triangle NQM$ are similar? They have two equal corresponding angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\angle P = \angle N$, ($\angle$ 's subtended same segment)

$\angle S=\angle Q=90^ \circ$

$\angle PMS = \angle NMQ$, (3rd $\angle$ of $\triangle$)

$\triangle PMS\sim \triangle NMQ$, (AAA similarity)

$$\frac{PM}{NM}=\frac{MS}{MQ}, \frac{16}{2\times MO}=\frac{MS}{10} $$
$$MO \times MS=80$$